# Jest TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, jest-enzyme

I am writing jest test case for a component but I keep getting this error:

```
    /mnt/pinboard/webapp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12056
      throw error;
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'body')
    at getActiveElement (/mnt/pinboard/webapp/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:1731:16)
```

It seems that I get this error when I am using mount() in my test case, I tried using shallow but it won’t meet my use case. Any idea on how I could solve this? Thanks!